# I am trying to remove characters in a string from a defined string. the error comes here: if(s.charAt(x) == punct.charAt(y))

Tags: java

```
String dirtyStr = "Who. do yo$u th,ink you    are?!";
         System.out.println(scrub(dirtyStr));
static String punct = ".,?!:;\"(){}{}<>"; 
      public static String scrub(String s)
      {         
         for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++)
         {
            for(int y = 0; y < punct.length(); y++)
                {
                    if(s.charAt(x) == punct.charAt(y))
                    {
                        s = s.replace("" + s.charAt(x), "");
                    }
                }       
         }
         return s;  
      }
```

Stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 28
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at StringMethods_7_Gupta.scrub(StringMethods_7_Gupta.java:120)
    at StringMethods_7_Gupta.main(StringMethods_7_Gupta.java:95)
```

Comment: You might wish to approach this a different way, such as looping through the original string, and only adding non-punctuation chars to a new string. You can use a String builder to speed things up

Comment: look into regex replace

Answer (score 3):

You are not keeping track of your `s.length()` it changes every time you replace a character. Just break out of the loop when you replace a character after you subtract 1 from the loop counter to check the new character at the replaced position to avoid skipping over consecutive punctuation.

```
String dirtyStr = "Who. do yo$u th,ink you    are?!";
System.out.println(scrub(dirtyStr));

static String punct = ".,?!:;\"(){}{}<>"; 

  public static String scrub(String s)
  { 
     for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++)
     {
        for(int y = 0; y < punct.length(); y++)
            {
                if(s.charAt(x) == punct.charAt(y))
                {
                    s = s.replace("" + s.charAt(x), "");
                    x--;
                    break;
                }
            }       
     }
     return s;  
  }
```

if you are looking at changing the implementation, you may simply use the regex to replace all punctuation with just a call to the `replaceAll()` method.

```
System.out.println(dirtyStr.replaceAll("[.,?!:;\"(){}{}<>]",""));
```

Comment: This still won't work, although it avoids the exception; the outer counting loop will skip consecutive punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a smidge drunk, but it looks like you check the length of your string at the beginning of the loop, then you start removing characters from it, and your loop overruns the end of the string.  You need a while loop I think, so you can check that your index is within bounds before every iteration.

```
int x = 0;
while(x < s.length())
         {
            for(int y = 0; y < punct.length(); y++)
                {
                    if(s.charAt(x) == punct.charAt(y))
                    {
                        s = s.replace("" + s.charAt(x), "");
                    }
                }   
            x++;    
         }
```

It's ugly cause I'm on a tablet, but I think it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing `s` with a shorter `s` but then still trying to go to the end of the original string. You'll also be missing consecutive punctuation, since you'll skip over them. You need to restart your `x` loop every time you get a match.

Answer (score 0):

So how about this, you keep the length of s in a variable and then every time you remove a character in s, you decrease s by 1 and the length by 1 too.
Should looks like this:

```
int aLength = s.length();
for(int x = 0; x < aLength; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < punct.length(); y++)
    {
            if(s.charAt(x) == punct.charAt(y))
            {
                    s = s.replace("" + s.charAt(x), "");
                    x--;
                    aLength--;
            }
     }       
}
return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one line:

```
public static String scrub(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[.,?!:;\"(){}\\[\\]<>]", "");
}
```

I also corrected the duplication if `{}`, assuming you meant to include `[]`.